# How can I know if one function belongs to .NET or C++?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I'm using .NET C++ on Visual Studio at the moment.

I know the differences between .NET and C++: C++ is a programming language and .NET is a framework based on C++, on this case. Correct me if I'm wrong.

But sometimes I ask some question here, on SO, and the users ask me if I'm talking about the .NET function or the C++ function. I supose that some C++'s functions are overrided by .NET, but I've not clear how can I distinguish if one function belongs to C++ or .NET.

Maybe it's a very simple question, but I'm not sure about this.

Comment: I think you are not allowed to mix managed and unmanaged C++. So either you are not using .Net, or you are using .Net exclusively.

Comment: You should tag your question with C++-cli, for a start ;) I'll do that this time, too.

Comment: @Rakete1111 C++-CLI is a set of extensions to c++ that let you combined managed and unmanaged C++.

Comment: So C++ does not use managed classes but objects yes. What's the main difference between this two things? Only garbage collector? Thank you

Comment: The C++/CLI compiler can compile any C++03 compliant code to MSIL.  That gets translated at runtime to machine code by the just-in-time compiler.  Just like managed code, but of course it does not have any of the benefits of managed code.  Like garbage collection and verifiability.  And doesn't have the benefit of native code, the optimizer built into the compiler spending its merry time finding the fastest machine code.  So there is no real "belongs to" category, you have to know yourself whether the code was compiled with /clr in effect.  Just a project setting.

Answer (score 2):

Read the docs as a first step (and usually the last). In visual studio, at least, you can just hit F1 to bring that up in a browser. That said, if the function takes or returns any managed references (eg. ones with a `^`) or if the class must be allocated with `gcnew` it is .net.

Regarding the specific issue from your last question (it was slightly whether an `array<>` was managed or unmanaged), the major issue was simply that your question lacked the [C++-CLI tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-cli), so the answerers were not immediately aware of the language you were using and assumed C++, as you did have that tag.

The specific issue of `array` is partially because you can use it in C++-CLI without having to add a `using namespace` or a `cli::` namespace qualification. Thankfully, the [cli namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d87eee3k(v=vs.90).aspx) only contains 4 things and is the only one to be imported implicitly into a C++-CLI project. Everything else in .net is part of a managed namespace (I believe), and it should be obvious which bits of functionality you're pulling in from those.

Comment: So C++-CLI is a C++ extension that adds managed objects. .NET is a Framework that, using C++-CLI, adds a huge API (methods for communications, UI, etc...). And .NET IS NOT C++-CLI (only uses it). Is all that true?

Comment: @areify that's pretty much correct, though I'd say that ".NET is a framework that can be accessed using C++-CLI, and it is possible that chunks of the .net framework you're using are written using C++-CLI. The key thing, as you've stated, is the difference between C++-CLI the language, and .NET the framework.

Comment: Great! Now I'm pretty sure about this. Thanks to you now I can tag my questions correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> ... and the users ask me if I'm talking about the .NET function or the C++ function.

I guess what the users want to know in this case is whether you are talking about the managed class or the unmanaged class inside your C++/CLI implementation. Actually, you can declare two types of classes in C++/CLI: A managed type, declared as "ref class" (sometimes called a wrapper class, too), or a plain native, unmanaged type, declared simply as "class".

The main difference is that you can use all .NET classes inside a "ref class", while the plain "class" acts like a normal C++ class. Moreover, the "ref class" has a lot of syntactic extensions required for interfacing the .NET framework, which the native "class" lacks.